# Fetching Related Object is null in mutil database with doctrine in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

```
config
    config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8

            customer:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: 'trade'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                      dir: EntityTrade


AppBundle\Entity\acclogin
class acclogin
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true)
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="can't empty!",groups={"registration","login"})
         * @Assert\Length(min=6,max=64,minMessage="invalid 1",maxMessage="invalid 1",groups={"registration","login"})
         */
        private $name;
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\EntityTrade\PayOrder",mappedBy="account")
         */
        private $payorders;

      public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         *
         * @return account_login
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
}

//AppBundle\EntityTrade\PayOrder
class PayOrder
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="can't empty!",groups={"payAdd"})
         */
        private $pay_id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\acclogin",inversedBy="payorders")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pay_id",referencedColumnName="name")
         */
        private $account;
      .....
     ....
     ...........here is getter and setter
}

//AppBundle\EntityTrade\PayOrderRepository
class PayOrderRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {
        public function get( PayOrder $payOrder ) {
            $pay_no = $payOrder->getPayNo();
            return $this->findOneBy( [ 'pay_no' => $pay_no ] );
        }
}
```

it throw a exception which is "Missing value for primary key id on AppBundle\Entity\acclogin" at this code "$this->findOneBy( [ 'pay_no' => $pay_no ] );"
    why?am i have to add a primary key on the "name",any body can help me?thank 
you very much !
    if i change the @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pay_id",referencedColumnName="name") to @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id"), i will work ,but $PayOrder->getAccount(),only the id has the data ,the name of acclogin is always null 。

Comment: the symfony and the doctrine version,
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine requires you to use the primary key on the join columns.

See the documentation for `JoinColumn()` here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_joincolumn

Particularly this line:

> **referencedColumnName**: Name of the primary key identifier that is used
>   for joining of this relation.

Comment: yeach,how to fix this?can you give me an example?

Comment: The code does not show everything but it seems like you are trying to get a PayOrder by `pay_no` which definition we cannot see in the code sample. Anyway, the query is not related to the `acc_login` entity, but the exception is being thrown because the @JoinColumn is pointing to a non primary key. Is there any reason you are referencing `name` instead of `id` in `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pay_id",referencedColumnName="name")`

Comment: i want the PayOrder table with "pay_id" match the "acclogin.name" connect to acclogin table,pay_id data is "test1",the acclogin.name is also "test1",that's why referenceing name instead of id,the id is just a number,but the PayOrder only has the 'acclogin.name" data on the pay_id field to relate 'acclogin' table

Comment: This is a DB design smell. You could omit the acclogin.id and have the name as the primary key on the acclogin table but a number is more efficient in terms of storage and performance, it can be auto-generated etc. Also, the name can change, and you don't want to change the primary key value, having foreign keys etc...  Optimally the `pay_id` is a numeric type pointing to the acclogin record.. If you want to query by name you can still put an index on it, and write a short DQL which includes the join and the search condition.

Comment: i edit the class acclogin with @index like this,but it stil throw an exception,
"Missing value for primary key id on AppBundle\Entity\acclogin",
here is my change,

 @ORM\Table(name="acclogin",indexes={@Index(name="search_idx", columns={"name"})})
class acclogin{
  .....
}

i have cleared the cache and update schema,but it sill throw an exception like that.